# Using AppCompat v21 or lower in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I updated  appcompat-v7 SDK to API 23. But i cannot reference it as a library in Eclipse if my project is set to API 21.
There is a solution with Android Studio in this link [Using AppCompat v22 or lower](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Migrating-to-the-AppCompat-Library) .
Is there any solution in Eclipse?

Thank you.

Comment: to precisely say Google has stopped support for eclipse.. better to move to android studio.